# doubt in a book proof from 'The Geometry of Fractal Sets'

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading the proof of existence of positive finite $H^s$-measure (Theorem 5.4) on page 67-68 of [The Geometry of Fractal Sets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521337054).I am not quite convinced that $E_k$ are closed set by the construction in the proof and I think it is not trivial to prove the $E_k$'s are closed in the case when $n>2$. Can someone explain it to me?Thnak you.

Comment: Could you please define these sets $E_k$ for the benefit of those of us who don't have a copy of that book in front of us?

Comment: http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=-Kwp-GrimCIC&pg=PA67&hl=zh-TW&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Why are you not convinced? The $E_k$ are bounded, so they are contained in a big binary cube. This cube can be pieced together from finitely many binary cubes with side lengths $2^{-k}$. The intersection of $E_k$ with those cubes is closed, so the union of those intersections is closed and equals $E_k$.

Comment: The binary cubes used in the proof are half open so that they are disjoint.for example,in one dimensional case,the I's are of the form [a,b)